# How to replace a Gerber Toe-push tub drain stopper?

Tags: drain, bathtub, fitting

I need to replace existing gerber toe-push tub popup stopper, because the rubber gasket is worn out. Below are images of the toe-push stopper.

[image: Gerber toe-push tub pop up stopper 1]

<sub>*Click on image for a larger version of the image.*</sub>

[image: Gerber toe-push tub pop up stopper 2]

<sub>*Click on image for a larger version of the image.*</sub>

The fitting on the toe-push appears to be either 10-24 or a M5.

Below is image of of the tub drain shoe

[image: Tub Drain Shoe]

The depth of the fitting in drain shoe is about 1 1/4 inches

I purchased Danco Replacement tub drain stopper.

[image: Danco drain tub toe push stopper]

<sub>*Click on image for a larger version of the image.*</sub>

**Issue:** The fitting the Danco replacement part is 5/16 inches or 3/8 inches. The fitting in the tub drain shoe is less than 5/16 inches. I think the fitting is may be 1/4 inches.

Anyone run into a similar issue and if so can share how the problem was solved.

What are possible alternative fittings or any another options?

**Note:** I also tried the [PF waterworks Fits 3/8 in.and 5/16 in. TubSTRAIN Universal Toe Touch (Tip Toe or Foot Actu.) Hair Catcher Bathtub Drain Stopper in CH](https://www.homedepot.com/p/PF-WaterWorks-Fits-3-8-in-and-5-16-in-TubSTRAIN-Universal-Toe-Touch-Tip-Toe-or-Foot-Actu-Hair-Catcher-Bathtub-Drain-Stopper-in-CH-PF0936-CH/303217336) appear worked but the gasket was too high thus didn't to the job.

Comment: My stopper push one side to lock down the other side to release has a replaceable rubber. There was no brand so I took it in to my speciality store and they had the correct seal for ~2.50$. Big box stores have generic parts that don’t always fit but specialty stores may have the part you need on the shelf. 2.50 for a small pice of rubber is a lot but much cheaper than a replacement that did not fit.

Comment: The stopper that you said would have *"worked but the gasket was too high"* is also for 5/16" or 3/8". So is the issue the thread size or not? Replacements come in various heights...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it, The fitting of the PF Waterworks stopper worked, but the gasket was too high. I went to homedepot, and could not find a gasket. Danco stopper appear to have a work able gasket but incorrect tread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take another look at PF waterworks TubSTRAIN Universal Toe Touch (Tip Toe or Foot Actu.) that is referenced in the question.

[image: PF Waterworks Tub Stopper Edited]

Per the image the TubStrain product has a #10-20 fitting included.

[image: TubStrain Adapter]

On the back of the package the adapter is referenced as “F”

[image: TubStrain Adapter Back]

Another issue to take note is the Gasket. If the gasket placed the wrong way the Toe Touch will not work. Make sure the larger diameter of the gasket is pointed toward the drain and the smaller diameter is pointed towards the silver cap. Like an umbrella.

[image: TubStrain Gasket]

Also sometimes the gasket doesn't work, because they are smaller than the drain opening. Danco sells the gasket only. Replace the PF waterworks gasket with the Danco Rubber Tub Drain Gasket.

[image: Rubber Tub Drain Gasket]

[Rubber Tub Drain Gasket in Black](https://www.homedepot.com/p/DANCO-Rubber-Tub-Drain-Gasket-in-Black-88209/202950229)

Answer (score 1):

Th PF Waterworks stopper linked in your question has two threaded adapters; one 5/16" thread and one 3/8 thread. Those screw it down to the strainer. Your question specifically mentions those threads as being incompatible, but then goes on to imply that the stopper thread **did work**, and that the stopper **height** is the issue. This contradiction makes your problem unclear to readers trying to help.

5/16" and 3/8" are the common strainer/stopper threads. The stoppers also come two different heights:
1 3/4" and 2". Assuming one or the other works for you:

- determine which thread works for you (5/16" is the smaller thread, 3/8" is the larger thread)
- go to the plumbing shop, where you should find two available heights for each thread size
- buy the one with your thread size that is shorter than the one you bought that was "too high"

Example catalog listing of 3/8" x 1 3/4" stopper and the taller 3/8" x 2" stopper:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding to the question. You are correct the PF waterworks toe-push drain stopper fittings did work. There were 3 fittings/adapter in the package. Unfortunately I return the stopper. The fitting to old stopper fits and M5 or 10-24 receptacle. Also the depth to the receptacle is about 1 1/4 inches. I have updated the body of the question with the new information.